# Why does the browser become unresponsive after multiple events using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

1 - I have this simple html button :

```
<input type="button" id="testBtn" value="1" />
```

2 - and some jquery :

```
function one()
{
    $("#testBtn").val("1")
    .click(function(){
        zero();
    });         
}

function zero()
{
    $("#testBtn").val("0")
    .click(function(){
        one();
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#testBtn").click(function(){
        zero();
    });
});
```

3 - after multiple click on the testBtn firefox shows this message :

```
A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete. Script: http://localhost/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2
```

after click continue firefox shows above message again.

4 - I used the following solution instead and was able to resolve the unresponsive dialog:

```
var state=1;

function onezero()
{
    if (state == 1)
    {
        $("#testBtn").val("0")
        .click(function(){
            one();
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $("#testBtn").val("0")
        .click(function(){
            one();
        });     
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#testBtn").click(function(){
        onezero();
    });
});
```

5 - and above solution works well, but why first solution kills jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you keep adding a click event every time. click() **does not** override the previous event.

```
    $("#testBtn").val("0")
    .off("click").on("click", function(){
        one();
    });
```

The bad thing with `off` is it will wipe out any other click event that may be attached to that element. That is bad. The better approach is to add one click handler and build the logic into that to what to do.

```
    $("#testBtn").data("state",false).val("0")
    .on("click", function(){
        var elem = $(this);
        var state = elem.data("state");
        if(state) {
            one();
        } else {
            two();
        }
        elem.data("state", !state);
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

The first solution attaches a new event handler every single time you click the button. You'd actually be better off with this:

```
document.getElementById('testBtn').onclick = function() {
    this.value = this.value == 1 ? 0 : 1;
};
```

Comment: So... that's what that code was trying to do. I gave up trying to figure it out.

Comment: thanks, but i want to run more code than above example, i just simplified the problem, and i have to use jquery

Comment: You can still use this code as a basis to work on. jQuery is never a requirement.

Comment: well if you where I worked and you used onclick, I would be upset since you may have just overrode other event handlers attached to the element. :)

Comment: @epascarello Ah, the joys of being the only programmer on the project XD

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/YFUuR/

Open up your console and take a look, as you keep clicking the button it keeps attaching more and more eventhandlers onto it. Eventually it all goes kaput.

Comment: thanks, in my local test ff console doesnt show anything when clicking but here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/YFUuR/) i figured out my problem reason

Answer (score 0):

You were overloading the element by adding unnecessary event handlers due to your references.